# Rewrite Rule if the images is not found

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite for redirecting any images which are not on the server to a default_image .Here is my rule , it is not working for now.Any suggestions.i am getting 404 instead.

```
RewriteCond ^/images/icons/small/(.*) !-f
RewriteRule ^/images/icons/small/display_profile.jpg ^/images/icons/small/$1 $
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that file name of your default image is `default_image`, you try something like this.
Put following lines in `.htaccess` of your document root.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/icons/small/.*\.jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ images/icons/small/default_image.jpg  [L]
```

Comment: Thnaks for the rule. When i use this i get directed to /var/www/images/icons/small/default_image.jpg . any clue why this happening?

Comment: Awesome i removed the redirect , I just want to serve the image if the default image is not being served.